# Set the DerivedData location in the same folder as project

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcodebuild

I have a workspace with 3 different targets, for one of them I need to get the result of the build inside the folder where my code is.

I also need to build this using xcodebuild, I've been researching trying to find if there is some flag or configuration thing to achieve this but couldn't find it...

Is there a way of doing this???

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this yet? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-locations_preferences/DerivedData/DerivedData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010523-CH2-SW1

Comment: yes, I've already read that, but the problem is that I need to build from xcodebuild command, no from xcode. And I need to create the derived data inside my project folder just and only for a build target...

Answer (score 1):

There is a flag in `xcodebuild` command for that

```
-derivedDataPath PATH - specifies the directory where build 
                        products and other derived data will go
```